# I am accidentally calling the Contentful API every couple of millisenconds

Tags: reactjs, api, contentful

I am trying to set up contentful on a react project. I have set it up and all of my data is displaying correctly, but when I go to the Network tab in devtools, I can see I'm sending API calls over and over. I tried to solve this by using isMounted but I think I must be using it wrong.

```
  const [aboutTypes, setAboutTypes] = useState([]);
  const { getAboutTypes } = useContentful();

  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted) {
      getAboutTypes().then((response) => response && setAboutTypes(response));

      return () => <></>;
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      setAboutTypes(null);
      setIsMounted(false);
    };
  }, []);
```

useContenful.js:

```
const getAboutTypes = async () => {
    try {
      const entries = await client.getEntries({
        content_type: "aboutType",
        select: "fields",
      });

      const sanitizedEntries = entries.items.map((item) => {
        const typeImage = item.fields.typeImage.fields;
        return {
          ...item.fields,
          typeImage,
        };
      });

      return sanitizedEntries;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
    }
  };
  return { getAboutTypes, getHerdMembers };
```

Comment: You forgot to add a dependencies array in your first `useEffect`. It should be like the 2nd one: `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a dependency list to `useEffect`, the same way you used it in the second call.

With no dependency list, the effect is run on **every render**.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted) {
      getAboutTypes().then((response) => response && setAboutTypes(response));

      return () => <></>;
    }
  }, []); // add empty array to call once
          // or add things in the array to run every time
          // one of the items in the array changes
```